# Class definition thinks setting a variable is a Unit?

Tags: scala

Writing out a Scala class and problem here is that the compiler thinks that the code is a unit not returning the proper value. It's a method used to set a property in the class:

```
def setObject(`object`:StripeObject):StripeObject = {
    this.`object` = `object`
  }
```

The error is: `type mismatch; found : Unit required: com.stripe.StripeObject`

The full class is:

```
case class EventData(var previousAttributes: HashMap[String,Object], var `object`:StripeObject) extends StripeObject {

  def getPreviousAttributes = {
    previousAttributes
  }

  def setPreviousAttributes(previousAttributes: HashMap[String, Object]) = {
    this.previousAttributes = previousAttributes
  }

  def getObject = {
    `object`
  }

  def setObject(`object`:StripeObject):StripeObject = {
    this.`object` = `object`
  }
}
```

How do I make sure it doesn't return a Unit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java setters are usually defined with `void` return type:

```
public void setObj(StripeObject name);
```

The Scala equivalent is `Unit`, which is also the value of an assignment expression. So in Scala you'd write a setter as one of the following (which are all equivalent, with the first being the most idiomatic):

```
def setObj(obj: StripeObject) {
  this.obj = obj
}

def setObj(obj: StripeObject): Unit = {
  this.obj = obj
}

def setObj(obj: StripeObject) = this.obj = obj
```

This is just a convention for setters, though, and you could easily return the value if you wanted:

```
def setObj(obj: StripeObject): StripeObject = {
  this.obj = obj
  obj
}
```

This would be a bit unusual, but wouldn't be likely to cause problems, even for callers who were expecting `Unit`.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to wrap my head around this, but in Scala assignments do not return a value as they do in Java. Not sure why they did this, but they did. Here's some sample code so you can see it in the Scala console:

```
scala> var number = 30
number: Int = 30

scala> var otherNumber = number = 40
otherNumber: Unit = ()
```

So you need to return the **`object`** in the method. Also, avoid using language keywords in your code like this, even though this is possible, it makes for code that's harder to read.

Comment: Interesting, yes not the first time I've heard to avoid `this`. Part of the trouble is I'm porting Java code to Scala, so I'm hitting bombs left and right LOL. i think the return behaviour is related to the desire to avoid "return" statements and speed up the compiler. But I'm not fully qualified to make that statement ;)

Comment: No, not **this**, I meant the use of the **object** keyword, you **should** use **this** ;D

Comment: whoops sorry that's my own fault :D

Comment: @DeLongey That's exactly the reason I heard from Odersky on a mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

In every case where you see

```
whatever = something
```

replace it with

```
whatever = something ; whatever
```

and you'll be fine.  Assignment *does* return `Unit`.  So simply restate what you want returned.